# React setInterval makes unnecessary code to execute

Tags: react-hooks, setinterval

I want to make clock with **useState, useEffect**, and **setInterval**. But when I run this code, "hello" is logged every second. In real code, another code is in place instead of "hello" which I really want to execute only one time. How can I solve this problem?
(Using useEffect is not essential.)

```
const [clock, setClock] = useState({ year: "", month: "", date: "", hours: "", minutes: "" });

console.log("hello")

useEffect(() => {
  const updateEverySecond = setInterval(() => {
    setClock(getClock());
  }, 1000);
  return () => {
    clearInterval(updateEverySecond);
  };
}, []);
```

In addition, this is the code of **getClock()**.

```
function getClock() {
  let now = new Date();
  var monthArray = new Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12);

  const year = String(now.getFullYear());
  const month = String(monthArray[now.getMonth()]);
  const date = String(now.getDate());
  const hours = String(now.getHours());
  const minutes = String(now.getMinutes()).padStart(2, 0);

  return { year, month, date, hours, minutes };
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You'd actually want to move the code you want to execute only one time into a useEffect hook. Similar to how you're using useEffect now where the code within your current hook executes only once because your dependency array (the second argument of useEffect) is empty. For purposes of code organization, you could simply create a second useEffect hook for whatever would replace console.log("hello"), but regardless of that, the end state would look something like this:

```
useEffect(() => {
  console.log("hello");
}, []);
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, In the above code hello will print every time. that is how React functional component works, on every rerender it will execute each line inside the function again, that's why is logging hello

But you can use one another useEffect without any state dependency([]) to achieve the one time call

```
 useEffect(() => {
    console.log("hello...");
    //this section will only run when component mount (only the first time)
  }, []);
```

here is a full working example
https://codesandbox.io/s/keen-ardinghelli-rmt3l?file=/src/App.js